# What is the history of 'The United Church of God'?

Tags: church-history

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Church_of_God) article regarding *The United Church of God* only gives contemporary information as does the [official website](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/who-is-god) of the denomination.

I note that the denomination does not believe in the personage of the Holy Spirit, thus appears to be binitarian, and that the denomination does not believe that humanity is created with an immortal soul and that the denomination does not believe in the eternal punishment of the wicked, but in annihilationism.

I am interested in the history of the organisation, briefly (not an extensive account) its main proponents over the last two hundred years and its known leaders over the past two hundred years and if it has any connection to Garner Ted Armstrong, or not.

---

The above are not my own beliefs and I am not interested in joining the organisation, just in its history.

Comment: Ask @RayButterworth -- [he seems to be quite knowledgeable in it](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/84616/50422).

Comment: For those with a sense of humour, Garner Ted Armstrong "appeared" on [The Intro & The Outro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMqdwtd8TrQ&ab_channel=SuperXavier30) recorded in Britain in 1967 by the Bonzo Dog Doo-Dah Band. (I like Ostinato music (repeating theme like "Bolero"), and this recording was part of the inspiration for Mike Oldfield's "Tubular Bells" in 1973). ¶ More directly, GTA's radio program was Merle Haggard's inspiration for "Okie From Muskogee", and Buck Owens asked GTA himself to perform two songs on a 1976 episode of "Hee Haw".

Comment: It's probably important to note that this is a very different denomination to that of the Uniting Church of Australia, which was formed by a union between the Australian Methodist, Presbyterian, and Congregationalist Churches.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You will not get an extensive account from me because it was formed in 1995 in Indianapolis, Indiana.

With the best will in the world, nobody is going to be able to trawl up much history for this international association given that it claims to have first formed only 27 years ago.

However, if the various people who got together in 1995 to start this association had come from a main religious group - having become dissatisfied with it, seeking to break away and reform under the new name of United Church of God, then there could be a great deal of pre-1995 history to be unearthed. Trouble is, they are not giving much of a clue about any such possibility on their official web-site.

In previous research I'd done years ago, looking for modern-day denominations that had become offshoots of the Worldwide Church of God, founded by Herbert W. Armstrong (he of *The Plain Truth* magazine till his demise in 1986), I noticed ***the United Church of God, an International Association.*** There were 13 others in that list. When new leadership took over the Worldwide Church of God, various teachings began to be changed or dropped. After ten years, the Worldwide Church of God had lost 130 of its 450 ministers, and saw at least 30,000 members scatter into 25 splinter churches, or drop out of church life entirely. Much information on this is in a main article in *Christian Research Journal*, Winter 1996, pp6-7 & 44 & 53

But so far, the waters are so muddied, I cannot see clear links.  It would be nice if any person in the United Church of God would give us a proper history [and thanks to those who subsequently have]. There would be much history to relate if it goes back to Armstrong in the 20th century.

Comment: "*Trouble is, they are not giving even a clue about any such possibility on their official web-site.*"  They give more than a clue.  Search it for "Herbert W. Armstrong" and you'll get hundreds of hits.  From a [Review of a book about their schism](https://www.ucg.org/beyond-today/review/autoentitylabel-0) to this year's [Visiting China with HWA](https://www.ucg.org/members/news/personal-from-the-president-july-15-2021), there are many explicit references to their origins.

Comment: "It would be nice if any person in the United Church of God would give us a proper history." Seriously, why would anyone bother with the process displayed here.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth We all know there’s plenty info about Armstrongism. Yet the Q was about the United Church of God but those going to their on-line info. don’t get a clue about any link with Armstrong, so why would we turn there? Only those ‘in the know’ take it as understood, but for outsiders like me and the PO, we have to search, wondering. Does the United Church of God have literature clearly showing their origins in Armstrongism? Their web-site doesn’t. Why not? Thanks for your answer, which I have not down-voted.

Comment: @steveowen  Of necessity, my process had to work from front to back to try to get any history for the United Church of God because its own history apparently doesn’t mention Armstrong. And I’m still searching to see if the history goes even further back to Swedenborg. Would any of the Swebenborgians on this site care to enlighten us if I ask a specific Q about that? But if there is no connection, just say so openly. Let those ‘in the know’ openly give us their religious history.

Comment: I never cease to wonder why people on SE will answer a Q if they have no knowledge of the matter. Surely, such things are best left to people who have an inherent understanding and not simply gurggle it. Being awarded best answer so soon is absurd.

Comment: @steveowen  Those of us who have partial knowledge ask Qs to increase it. And I answered with what info I already had, hoping that might encourage the more knowledgeable to answer. One has spoken disdainfully of Wiki info. on the matter but you will be glad to know I almost never search Wiki for knowledge. I prefer printed books and articles. Your quarrel with the speed of an appointed BA lies with the PO.

Comment: @Anne says she  doesn't "*get a clue about any link with Armstrong*".
On the home [United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/) web page, type "origins of the church" into the search.
The first result in the list is [A Brief History of the Church](https://www.ucg.org/sermons/a-brief-history-of-the-church), which begins with "*In this sermon Mr. Smith presents a history of the church primarily over the last 80 years showing the growth under Mr. Armstrong and the decline over the past twenty years.*".
That's a lot more than a clue, and a lot more open and honest than one might have expected.

Comment: @Anne "*did discover a page where they brought up four links about biblical beliefs as related to the teachings of Emmanuel Swedenborg*".
If you mean [Search Results](https://www.ucg.org/bcse/search/swedenborg), only one of those linked articles contains "Swedenborg", and that is in a comment from a reader.  I'd guess the others got indexed the same way and the irrelevant comments were later removed.
Other than coincidence, am unaware of any connection with Swedenborg.

Comment: @Anne says "*I answered with what info I already had*". But most of that answer is about how you were unable to find anything, plus some unfounded speculation.  The only real content is that the UCG was an offshoot of the WCG.

Comment: @Anne says "*There would be much history to relate if it goes back to Armstrong in the 20th century*". Read HWA's autobiography for how the original church developed, and Raising the Ruins for how the organization split. (Page 125–126 even talks about the origins of the United Church of God.) ¶ "*and a wealth of history if that can even be traced back to the 18th century and Swedenborg*". It can't.

Comment: As a Swedenborgian minister and scholar, I am not aware of any connection between Swedenborg and the Herbert W. Armstrong churches. Certainly the doctrines of those churches bear little or no resemblance to what Swedenborg taught.

Comment: Also, the statement about Swedenborg in *The Hutchinson Softback Encyclopedia* is very poorly researched. Swedenborg is not considered a prophet by Swedenborgians, nor does he ever call himself a prophet. His writings are not "the scriptures of the sect," though a break-away group did declare them to be the Word of God—something Swedenborg himself never said. He wrote many more works than *Divine Love and Wisdom.* The Swedenborg Society in London is only one of the Swedenborgian publishers. And on and on. The writer of this article had very little knowledge of the Swedenborgian movement.

Comment: @Lee Woofenden  The Encyclopedia has no articles in it about anything. It gives succinct, basic info and takes no stance on anything. I'm glad clarity has been established, showing there's no connection between Swedenborg and the WWC of Armstrong. I'm now wondering if several people on here are out to get my answer removed. No matter. I've saved it and all the comments.

Comment: At minimum, the part suggesting a connection to Swedenborg should be removed from your answer, since in fact there is no connection. And succinct or not, the statement from that encyclopedia is misleading. There is a huge amount of misinformation about Swedenborg floating about, especially in conservative Christian circles. This statement simply perpetuates some of that misinformation. The scriptures of the Swedenborgians are found in the Bible, not in Swedenborg's writings.

Comment: @Lee Woofenden  Yes, I shall remove parts of my answer about Swedenborgianism. I must comment, however, that they are not unique in claiming to find their beliefs in the Bible and not in the writings of men who founded the denomination. Groups that are far beyond mainstream Christianity make the same protests when they are not presented to their liking in sites like this. If I dared named two of them here, they would drop on me like a ton of bricks. So I won’t. Not in this answer, which is not related to the question. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for making that correction to your answer. I'd be happy to discuss your other points further in the Upper Room chatroom if you like. Just ping me there.

Answer (score 2):

Herbert W. Armstrong was raised a Quaker but was not especially religious.
His wife associated with some Seventh Day Adventists, and after he called them fanatics, she gave him a challenge to prove, *from the Bible* the doctrine of observing the sabbath on Sunday.
He took up the challenge, studied and research the topic endlessly, and eventually had to admit that his wife was right, there really was no biblical support for Sunday.

Having discovered that what he had considered one of the fundamental doctrines of Christianity *wasn't* Biblical, he became obsessed with the idea and began researching other doctrines.
When most of them too fell in turn, he himself became what others might call a religious fanatic, and began preaching the truths that he had discovered, at first locally and then on a radio program.

He felt that God was leading him to the truth, but never did he claim to have received any divine revelations, prophecies, or new truths.
The truth was there in the Bible for everyone to see, if they were only willing to read it for themselves.
Many times he would say, "*Blow the dust off your Bible and prove it for yourself. Don't believe me, believe the Bible.*".

Armstrong did not teach that he had founded a new church or found a new truth.
The religion he preached was a continuation of the same small church that has has existed since the days of the Apostles.
See [A TRUE History of the TRUE CHURCH by Herman L Hoeh, 1959](https://www.hwalibrary.com/cgi-bin/get/hwa.cgi?action=getbklet&InfoID=1326548695).

To promote this truth, he published *The Plain Truth* magazine and founded the Radio Church of God in 1933.
This later became the Worldwide Church of God, with radio and television programs around the world in many languages.
The magazine's subscriptions were exceeded only by *TV Guide*.

The [Autobiography of Herbert W. Armstrong](https://www.thetrumpet.com/literature/books_and_booklets/2299) is available for online viewing, downloadable, or as a printed book (over 900 pages).

His son, Garner Ted Armstrong, was his heir apparent, and in the 1970s was the face on "The World Tomorrow" television program.
By 1978 though, internal disagreements in the organization led to GTA's excommunication, and his founding of the Church of God International, which had effectively the same religious doctrines as the original church.

HWA continued leading the WCG until his death in 1986.
During that time he continued as an ambassador for Christianity.
He was also recognized as an ambassador for world piece, being received by hundreds of political leaders around the world.
"*Mr. Armstrong contributed to sharing the word of the Lord with his community and with people throughout the nation. You can take pride in his legacy.*" — U.S. President Ronald Reagan

Church membership exceeded 100,000 tithe-paying members.
The Church and its teachings had an appeal to intelligent and logical thinking people, rather than the emotional appeal used by most other denominations.

His book, [Mystery of the Ages](https://www.thetrumpet.com/literature/books_and_booklets/730), published in 1985 was a summary of the church's doctrines.
This book, like all their publications, was sent free of charge to anyone that requested it.
The organization never solicited anyone but their own members for donations.

Following HWA's death, the church continued in the same path for a few years, but then began a process of changing their doctrines, revising, dropping, or charging for their publications, and generally moving toward mainstream Christianity.
Many in the ministry objected to this direction, and over the next few years the vast majority of them broke away at various times, forming their own denominations, each claiming to be a true continuation of Armstrong's teaching.

The remaining church, which by now had accepted Sunday worship, the Trinity, unclean food, Christmas, and just about every doctrine that distinguished the original church from mainstream Christianity, renamed itself to Grace Communion International.
The church was now much much smaller and far far richer, having sold off the assets that had belonged to the much larger organization (e.g. Bible college campuses in England and California), and the luxurious [Ambassador Auditorium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambassador_Auditorium) in Pasadena, whose acoustics were so perfect that many artists (e.g. Arthur Rubenstein and Herbert von karajan) refused to perform anywhere else on the west coast.

(The Wikipedia article on the Worldwide Church of God is extremely bad, making it look like the original church saw the error of its ways and finally managed successfully to join the National Association of Evangelicals.)

Meanwhile, the spinoff churches continued to grow and promote the truth, again giving freely to all that asked.
Some accept each other as equally legitimate parts of God's Church; others don't.

There are many smaller groups, but the United Church of God is probably the largest and most conservative, along with the Living Church of God.
The Reformed Church of God and the Philadelphia Church of God are much stronger on applying prophecy to specific current events and have in some ways made additions to the original beliefs.
Most differences appear to be over leadership rather than doctrine though.

The Philadelphia Church of God continued publishing Herbert W. Armstrong's books and booklets, and was sued by Grace Communion International for copyright violation.
The issue wasn't that the copyright holders were demanding royalties for the publication (the PCG would have willingly paid), but that they were using copyright law to suppress the publication of material they disagreed with.
The case made its way to the US Supreme Court [WORLDWIDE CHURCH OF GOD v. PHILADELPHIA CHURCH OF GOD INC](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-9th-circuit/1193707.html)

Unfortunately, the PCG ended up losing that case (the minority report is worth reading), but surprisingly the winning side later simply sold the copyright to them.
The entire story of this court battle (and the church history summarized above and much more) is described in full in [Raising the Ruins](https://www.thetrumpet.com/literature/books_and_booklets/967).

That book, and the others linked above thanks to the copyright purchase, are all provided free of charge by the Philadelphia Church of God.

Disclaimer: I have never been a member of any of the organizations mentioned or implied above.
I do however find their doctrines, derived by biblical exegesis without using tradition or other non-biblical sources, to be far more logically consistent and simpler than any other denomination I've encountered.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth, thanks, and for clarifying there's no link with the UCG and Swedenborg. I won't need to ask any Q on that, now! But I'd never have thought to read HWA's biography without first knowing the UCG sprang from the WWG - not mentioned till p125. If the UCG had called itself WWG Continuing, that would have made the link clear. I've noted all your other comments under my answer.