# How do non-LDS believers in the modern restoration (or continuation) of the offices of apostle and prophet rebut GotQuestions.org's objections?

Tags: apostles, prophets, cessationism, continuationism, restoration

I'm specifically talking about the GotQuestions.org article [*Is God restoring the offices of apostle and prophet in the church today?*](https://www.gotquestions.org/apostles-prophets-restored.html)

A summary of the main arguments (in my own words) from the article would be the following:

- The office of apostle belonged exclusively to the original 12 + Matthias + Paul.
- The uppercase Apostles set up the foundation for the universal church in the 1st century (Ephesians 2:20), therefore their job is already done, and the office is no longer necessary.
- There is the gift of apostle, which must not be confused with the office of apostle. The gift of apostle continues, whereas the office ceased in the first century (if I'm not misunderstanding the article).
- The gift of prophecy was a temporary gift necessary for laying the foundation (Ephesians 2:20 again), but once the canon of Scripture was complete, prophets were no longer necessary and ceased.
- The current teaching of the restoration of prophets and apostles is unbiblical (see the article for details).
- The Bible uses past tense when it talks about prophets, apostles, even miracles and gifts of the Spirit. The article seems to be making the case, then, that the past tense is indicative of cessation.

**How do non-LDS believers in the modern restoration or continuation of the offices of apostle and prophet rebut this article?**

---

**Appendix - the article itself (it's relatively short)**

> The movement to restore the offices of apostle and prophet bases the
> claim that apostles and prophets are to be a part of the church on
> Ephesians 4:11-12. These verses say, "And He gave some as apostles,
> and some as prophets, and some as evangelists, and some as pastors and
> teachers, for the equipping of the saints for the work of service, to
> the building up of the body of Christ."
>
> During the first century of the church, there was an office of apostle
> and there was a spiritual gift of apostle. The office or position of
> apostle was held by the 12 disciples of Jesus plus Matthias, who took
> Judas’ place, and Paul. Those who held the office or position of
> apostle were chosen specifically by Christ (Mark 3:16-19). The
> replacement for Judas is seen in Acts 1:20-26. Note in this passage
> that Judas' position was called an office. It should also be noted
> that Paul was chosen by Christ (1 Corinthians 15:8-9; Galatians 1:1;
> 2:6-9). These men were given the task of setting up the foundation of
> the church. It should be understood that it was for the universal
> church that these men were a part of the foundation (Ephesians 2:20).
> The foundation of the church (universal church) was laid in the first
> century. This is why the office of apostle is no longer functioning.
>
> There was also a spiritual gift of apostle (this is not to be confused
> with the office—they are separate). Among those who had the spiritual
> gift were James (1 Corinthians 15:7; Galatians 1:19), Barnabas (Acts
> 14:4, 14; 1 Corinthians 9:6), Andronicus and Junias (Romans 16:7),
> possibly Silas and Timothy (1 Thessalonians 1:1; 2:7), and Apollos (1
> Corinthians 4:6, 9). This latter group had the gift of apostleship but
> not the apostolic "office" conferred upon the Twelve and Paul. Those
> who had the gift of apostle, then, were those who carried the gospel
> message with God’s authority. The word "apostle" means "one sent as an
> authoritative delegate." This was true of those who held the office of
> Apostle (like Paul) and those who had the spiritual gift (like
> Apollos). Though there are men like this today, men who are sent by
> God to spread the gospel, it is best NOT to refer to them as apostles
> because of the confusion this causes since many are not aware of the
> two different uses of the term apostle.
>
> The gift of prophet was a temporary gift given by the Christ for the
> laying of the foundation of the universal church. Prophets also were
> foundational to the universal church (Ephesians 2:20). The prophet
> proclaimed a message from the Lord for the believers of the first
> century. These believers did not have the advantage we have of having
> a complete Bible. The last book of the New Testament (Revelation) was
> not completed until late in the first century. So the Lord provided
> gifted men called prophets who proclaimed messages from God to the
> people until the canon of Scripture was complete.
>
> It should be noted that the current teaching of the restoration of
> prophet and the office of apostle is far from what Scripture describes
> of the men who held the gift of prophet and the office of apostle.
> Those who teach the restoration of the office teach that the men who
> claim to be apostles and prophets should never be spoken against,
> should never be questioned, because the person who speaks against them
> is speaking against God. Yet, the Apostle Paul commended the people of
> Berea for checking what he said against the Word of God to make sure
> he spoke the truth (Acts 17:10-11). The Apostle Paul also stated to
> those in Galatia that if anyone, including himself, should teach
> another Gospel, that person should be "accursed" (Galatians 1:8-9). In
> everything, Paul kept pointing people to the Bible as the final
> authority. The men who claim to be apostles and prophets today make
> themselves the final authority, something Paul and the Twelve never
> did.
>
> It should also be noted that Scripture refers to these men in the past
> tense. 2 Peter 3:2 and also Jude 3-4, state that the people should not
> stray from the message the apostles gave (past tense). Hebrews 2:3-4
> also speaks in the past tense of the those who performed (in the past)
> signs, wonders, miracles, and gifts of the Holy Spirit.

**Note:** The article also links to a 5 min YouTube video [*Is God restoring the offices of apostle and prophet in the church today? | GotQuestions.org*](https://youtu.be/F5281FieeKo) (in case you may prefer to watch the video instead).

---

For those interested in the Latter-day Saint perspective on a similar article: [How do Latter-day Saints rebut Don Stewart's article "Are There Still Apostles Today?"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90502/50422)

Comment: I feel like these questions as multiple questions in one by positing multiple objections. Not sure but that’s just how I see it.

Comment: @LukeHill - that's a fair point, but on the other hand, splitting this into 6 separate questions would be sort of too much as well.

Comment: you post multiple questions a day. It wouldn’t be thattttt bad. Either way I’m not going to close, as I’m unsure about whether or not it’s acceptable.

Comment: can you clarify how your previous [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90502/22319) doesn't address some of these?

Comment: @depperm - there is certainly some overlap on the apostle side of the question, so I wouldn't claim that.

Comment: The prophet part is different, but much of this overlaps with another currently active thread, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90502/how-do-believers-in-the-modern-continuation-of-the-office-of-apostle-rebut-don-s

Comment: @LukeHill and depperm.  Agreed with Luke that it's too much too split.  Like a Q in the *Summa* which contains many objections that show multiple facets of the Q, it's narrow enough, contains objective criteria, but scope maybe too wide since the other Q reveals that LDS understanding of apostles (restoration) is different than mainstream (continuous succession like Catholics, Anglicans, Eastern Orthodox).  How do we handle it in C.SE?  One suggestion is to restrict this one to non-LDS and possibly tightening the other to LDS.

Comment: To @SpiritRealmInvestigator The other Q didn't answer GQ's point about past tense, so that's one non-overlapping part.  But LDS being restorationist trumps that point.  In my opinion if you update the scope of both questions as suggested, we can preserve both LDS answers in the other Q while protecting this Q from being closed-duplicate.  Another point I just noticed is the keyword in the title.  It should be switched since the answers to the other Q is actually "restoration", so if we want to make this Q different, this one should be about "continuation".

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - that's a good suggestion, which I'm going to pay heed to.

Comment: Good call to make the title "restoration or continuation" since it appears that from the opposing side (like Reformed and GotQuestion) they call it "restoration" but from the defending side they call it "continuation".  It's really yet another evidence how language (and thus label) is used for group identity !!

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I wasn't necessarily requesting to narrow to LDS, I was wondering if he could at least explain why the other question, which has overlap on a few, doesn't satisfy the overlapped questions here-as even though the other the other is LDS tagged is mostly logical inconsistencies IMO

Comment: @depperm I think I understand your perspective.  I'm giving opinion to help prevent duplicate questions, since Don Stewart and GotQuestion objections are practically the same, so you made the right call to ask what's the difference.  I think more specific scoping turns out to be needed, so I think we're in a good place (C.SE wise).  If LDS want to improve their answer (by answering GQ specific objection), they can do that in the other Q.  Similarly, we can dedicate this Q for non-LDS who can also address Don Stewart specific objection.

Comment: Since Latter-day Saint views are no longer in scope for this question, I responded to some of these thoughts from a Latter-day Saint perspective in a [second answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/90572/51818) to the parallel question.

Comment: I have found an article published by GotQuestions.org written by someone who holds to continuationism." We thought it would be worthwhile to have an article that positively presents continuationism, as it is always good for our viewpoints to be challenged, motivating us to further search the Scriptures to make sure our beliefs are biblically sound."  Is this what you are looking for?  https://www.gotquestions.org/continuationism.html